# Parent process doesn't wait for the child process to terminate

Tags: c, fork, exec

I'm trying to write a C code with three processes, each one with its own purpose:

- First process: it has to allow the user to write a source code in C in a new terminal window.
- Second process: it has to compile the source code the user has just written in C.
- Third process: it has to execute the compiled file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define PATH_LENGTH 1024
#define ARGS_LENGTH 5
int main(){
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
                pid_t pid2;
                pid2 = fork();
                if(pid2 == 0){
                        char path[PATH_LENGTH];
                        getcwd(path, PATH_LENGTH); 
                        strcat(path, "/source.c");
                        char *args[ARGS_LENGTH] = {"gnome-terminal", "--", "nano"};
                        args[3] = path;
                        args[4] = NULL;
                        execvp(args[0], args);

                }
                else{
                        wait(NULL);
                        system("gcc source.c -o source");
                }
        }
        else{
                wait(NULL);
                system("./source");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I have a doubt about this code. As soon as I run it nano opens correctly on a new window but the parent process that opens nano doesn't wait for it to finish: it's like it ignores the `wait(NULL)`.

It's not the first time I use the system call, `exec*()`, and the other times the parent process waited. The only thing that raises a doubt for me is the fact that I open a new terminal window.

P.S.
I am not asking for the solution to the problem. I am just curious and interested about the problem and especially what happens to that `wait(NULL)` of the parent process of the process that opens `nano`.
I have tried to use the `system()`, to open the new terminal window, function but the result is the same, in this case obviously.

Comment: I would speculate that your `gnome-terminal` command is spawning a process, which is creating some other processes that continue to run, but is terminating by itself.

Comment: You should try to start `nano` by itself, without the gnome-terminal part (run the C-program from the command line in a terminal, so that `nano` already has access to a terminal).

Comment: You need to run `gnome-terminal` with the `--wait` option.

Comment: I'm not sure you need `ARGS_LENGTH` as a `#define`. This surely varies on a case-by-case basis. Don't forget you can do `char *args[] = { "x", "y", z, NULL }` and it'll size it automatically.

Comment: Do you _really_ want to do _nested_ `fork` calls? Or, do you just want to do the equivalent of: `gnome-terminal -- nano source.c ; gcc -o source source.c ; ./source`?

Comment: @CraigEstey: Maybe `gnome-terminal -- nano source.c && gcc -o source source.c && ./source` — where the `&&` replaces the `;`, so that the next program only runs if the current succeeds?

Comment: You don't print any diagnostic information.  You should capture the result of `wait()` and the exit status of the program, and then print it somewhere.  For example: `int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status);`.  Adding times to this would be overkill unless you've got logging code that does it anyway.  IMO, this is a basic minimum step to debugging the problems.  The chances are this would show you that the process launched exits successfully almost immediately.  Adding `--wait` should fix that.

Comment: Instead of `nano`, you should examine the environment variable EDITOR and use that.  Only use `nano` (really?) if EDITOR is not set.